# Reset my password for Gmail and Facebook

Tags: gmail, facebook, password-recovery

I have a new smart phone and can't log in to Facebook and email because I have forgotten my password for both of them. What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

Before reseting your password, please make sure of the following:

- The keyboard you are using is correct. (Check also if changing between different modes—QWERTY or QWERTZ—helps.)
- You are entering the correct email/username (check for caps, periods and commas).
- Make sure you are visiting to the official website of each of the respective sites (**https**:/facebook.com and **https**://mail.google.com)
- If you believe that the password you are using should be working and isn't your account(s) might have been hijacked. You can contact Facebook about it at http://www.facebook.com/hacked and Google at the same URL to reset your password.

If you think everything from your side is OK, you can go to he following two pages to reset your passwords respectively.

- To reset your Gmail password, please [click here](https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/)
- To reset your Facebook password, please [click here](https://www.facebook.com/login/identify?ctx=reason)