# Forgot passwords due to water damage

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-recovery

I just replaced my phone from water damage and forgot my Gmail and Facebook passwords.

How do I retrieve them?

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/67524/reset-my-password-for-gmail-and-facebook

Answer (score 0):

To reset **Gmail** password:

1. Visit [Google's Account Recovery](https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery) page.
2. Select the **I don't know my password** option.
3. Follow the instructions shown.

For more details: [Manage your Google Account password](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/41078?hl=en)

To reset **Facebook** password:

1. Go to the Facebook login page and click Forgot your password? or Can't login? in the top right.
2. Fill out the form to identify your account.
3. Select I forgot my password on the next page if prompted.
4. Look at the list of email addresses listed on your account.

For more details: [How do I reset my password](https://www.facebook.com/help/213395615347144)